# Out-File text input inside of a variable defined filepath in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell GUI script that is taking simple inputs from the user. the inputs are stored as following:

`trackingnumber = "enter tracking number: " + $txtTrack.Text`

I also have a dynamic folder that I would like to write to created that is named based off of the user input

`folderOut = "\\\C:\Users\name\Desktop\" + $($txtTrack.Text)`

I am trying to write the user input in a simple text file inside of that dynamic folder (folderOut)

I tried using:
 `$txtTrack.Text | out-file -FilePath ($folderOut + ($txtTrack.Text) + ".txt")`

However, it never saves inside of the $folderOut custom folder path it just saves on the desktop.
How can I save the user's input in a text file inside of the dynamic folder path ($folderOut)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where `trackingnumber` is used in your commands listed, but if the GUI text box is `$txtTrack` and you are using that as the tracking number input then the below should work.

```
$folderOut = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\" + $($txtTrack.Text)
$txtTrack.Text | out-file -FilePath ($folderOut + ".txt")
```

Previously you had it as `($folderOut + ($txtTrack.Text) + ".txt")`. Assuming the tracking number was `123` then the output file would write `123` into the text file called `C:\Users\name\Desktop\123123.txt` as you doubled up the `$txtTrack.Text` in the file path.

If you have an `OnClick` event for a button or something, I would recommend doing som error checking to ensure the text box has valid text inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to use `Join-Path` to concatenate directories.

```
folderOut = Join-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop') -ChildPath $txtTrack.Text
$txtTrack.Text | Out-File -FilePath ($folderOut + ($txtTrack.Text) + ".txt")
```